# Fortify Vulnerability + Path Manipulation

Tags: java, file, fortify

I am getting Path Manipulation issue in Fortify analysis tool.

```
private static final String ALLOWABLE_CHARS= "[\\\\/a-zA-Z0-9_\\-~:]+";
public static void generateZipFile(MultipartFile file) {
        File tempFile;
        try {
            String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
      
        // Reject any file path not containing any of the provided characters
        if (path.matches(ALLOWABLE_CHARS)) {
            tempFile = Files.createTempFile(Paths.get(path).normalize(), "prefix", "suffix").toFile();
            //Rest of the code
            .
            .
            .
```

}

**The vulnerability details from the tool:**

Attackers can control the file system path argument to get() , which allows them to access or modify otherwise protected files.

```
getProperty(return) -> Assignment to path ->  get(0)
Paths.get(path) -> String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
```

**In the above code , I tried two options to eliminate the vulnerability.**

1. I used normalize method for the path
2. Set the allowable chars in regular expression and tried to validate the path with that regex.

Both of the attempts do not solve the issue .  Anyone has any thoughts to solve this vulnerability issue?

Comment: you seem to need stop using that kind of poor quality software, if it generates false positives for such simple cases that only means it does not work at all, it is highly likely it may miss real vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reported in the line ,
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")

Instead of creating the temp directory under the the default system tmp directory path , I used the below code and it solved the fortify issue

Path path = Files.createTempDirectory("tmpdir");